# Dynamic <style> tag not applying styles to classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

this seems to be simple - but it's excruciatingly frustrating.

I've built a chat application for a school project.  It's .NET signalR and jquery spaghetti.  This is not production ready code whatsoever.  However, my non-tech family likes to log into it to chat during the day occasionally

Recently traffic has picked up enough that I'd like to differentiate usernames by color.  So on adding a user to the chatHub I run something like this:

```
var color = randomColor({ luminosity: 'dark', count: 1 });
var className = "span.user-name.user" + id.split('-')[0];
$("<style type='text/css'>." + className + "{color:" + color + ";}</style>").appendTo("head");
```

As you can see I'm using extreme specificity.  And I can see the actual `<style>` appear in my chrome inspector.

[image: style shown in <code><head></code> in inspector]

Unfortunately, the class doesn't seem to affect the actual element.  Here's the element in the inspector.

[image: actual element]

I'm not entirely sure **what** the problem is.  I've tried adding the following:

1. Adding to the `<body>` instead of the `<head>`.
2. Increasing specificity more and more.
3. Changing it in the inspector.stylesheet (works here).
4. Ensuring that I didn't start any classes with numbers (CSS 2?)
5. Running thru CSS validators.

I'm out of ideas of what else to try.  I would definitely appreciate it if some css ninja could tell me what I've done wrong here.

P.S.  Boy this is embarrassing.  Thanks guys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you are building the CSS string is inserting a `.` before `span` (which is a tag, not a class). Remove that and all should work:

```
var color = randomColor({ luminosity: 'dark', count: 1 });
var className = "span.user-name.user" + id.split('-')[0];
$("<style type='text/css'>" + className + "{color:" + color + ";}</style>").appendTo("head");
```

Comment: Classic case of too much looking elsewhere.  Lol, thanks @Rob.

Comment: Little things like that are always out to get us! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Did you just do `.span`? `span` is not a class, remove the dot `.`

Comment: yep  :(   Thanks Poly.  I blame brand new baby.

Comment: You have a brand new baby? :D In that case I'll let it slip :D

Answer (score 2):

Remove the dot before classname as span is element not class:

```
$("<style type='text/css'>" + className + "{color:" + color + ";}</style>").appendTo("head");
```